# How to get a list of running services from one docker container

Tags: node.js, docker

I have a node.js application running in Docker (using `docker-compose`).

I would like for it to use a list of the other services running (name, labels, etc.).

Is there a way **from within** one container to get a list of other services I can access?

Here's an example:

```
version: "3"
services:
  service_1:
    container_name: service_1
    labels: label_1
  service_2:
    container_name: service_2
    labels: label_2
  service_3
    container_name: service_3
    labels: label_3
```

Within `service_1`, is there a way to get a list of the other services (service_2, service_3, etc.)?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/ps/

Comment: @FelixFong I don't have access to the `docker` cli from within the container, unless you mean I should install docker within each of them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Docker's Engine REST API from within the container if you mount the Docker UNIX socket into the container.
To do so, you need to append `-v /var/run/docker.sock /var/run/docker.sock` to the command that you use to start your container. After that, you can call the API using that socket:

`npm i -s request request-promise-native` / `yarn add request request-promise-native`.

```
const request = require("request-promise-native")
const sock = "unix:/var/run/docker.sock"
const endpoint = `http://${sock}/v1.24`

function getRunningContainers () {
  const endpoint = `${endpoint}/containers/json`
  return request.get(endpoint)
}

(async () => {
  try {
    let containers = await getRunningContainers()
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }

  console.log(containers)
})()
```

Documentation for the Engine API can be found here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.24/

Answer (score 0):

you need run docker daemon (windows) first, and type `docker ps`to check your sevices is running.